# jquery mobile changepage and refresh page

Tags: javascript, url, jquery-mobile

I am new to web-development and have built a website consisting of:

- index.html
- graph.html
- myScript.js

The graph.html is building up the content due to given parameter, specified on what you do in the main page (`index.html`). After having a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840611/jquery-mobile-get-data-passed-to-page-via-changepage), I came up with this changePage call in my `myScript.js` when a button is clicked:

```
$.mobile.changePage('graph.html', { dataUrl: 'graph.html?ip='+id, data: { 'ip': id }, transition: "slide", changeHash: true, reloadPage : true} );
```

Thereby, `id` is just a `String` (e.g.: `load-21`) and I make an ajax-call with the help of the `id`.
The resulting `URL` looks like this: *http://192.168.131.11:18069/CoDEViewTest/#graph.html?ip=load-21*

Now the first call works fine, but if I hit refresh (F5) when I am on the `graph.html` page, I automatically get back to the main page (`index.html`), but I still have the same `URL` (*http://192.168.131.11:18069/CoDEViewTest/#graph.html?ip=load-21*  ). The behaviour I would like to have, is that the `graph.html` is reloaded. I found out that it works, if I call changePage like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage('graph.html?ip=' + id, { transition: "slide", changeHash: true, reloadPage : true} );
```

In this case,the `URL` is a bit different (note: there is no '#' in the `URL`): *http://192.168.131.11:18069/CoDEViewTest/graph.html?ip=load-21*
And in this case, when refreshing the page, I stay on the `graph.html`.

Now my question is, what is the difference between these two calls? Also, from my first impression after googling, I think that the second call is not a good practise. Therefore, I would like to work with the first call, but I need to stay on `graph.html` when refreshing the page..

Thanks

Comment: If you're still struggling with this, I recently released a [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) which may help you with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand this you must look at a basis of how jQuery Mobile works.

It uses **`AJAX`** to load pages into the **`DOM`**. Only first page is fully loaded, that means it **`HEAD`** and **`BODY`** content is loaded into the **`DOM`**. Every subsequent **`HTML`** page will me mostly discarded, basically only div with **`data-role="page"`** will be loaded into the **`DOM`**. Even more only one **`data-role="page"`** div will be loaded, every other page div will be discarded like rest of the page.

It is a normal state if you think about it. We already have **`HEAD`** from initial **`HTML`** page, we don't need another one.

This said, when you send parameter from one **`HTML`** page to another you are basically sending it to your initial **`HTML`** page. Remember what I have told you, subsequent pages are discarded so in your case page **`graph.html`** don't exist, its content is assimilated to **`index.html`**. Basically what was one a page inside a graph.html is now page inside a **`index.html`**.

Lets go even further. You have forced page reload with **`reloadPage : true`** but from link point of view this is still **`index.html`**. If you take a look:

```
http://192.168.131.11:18069/CoDEViewTest/#graph.html?ip=load-21
```

There's a hash # between / and **`graph.html`**. And that hash is a problem here. This is not an error, it is simply how jQuery Mobile works. If you press F5 in this case you will invoke **`index.html`** refresh.

In your other case, a situation is a little bit different. This case is working correctly mainly because you are refreshing your page and parameters set after the **`graph.html`** are preventing jQuery Mobile from attaching page hash #. This call acts as a real page reload and final link looks like this:

```
http://192.168.131.11:18069/CoDEViewTest/graph.html?ip=load-21
```

Because # don't exist thus **`DOM`** is fully empty from jQuery Mobile content there's nothing here that can hijack loading logic thus **`graph.html`** will reload again into **`graph.html`**.

#### EDIT :

I should also note that there's nothing wrong with your second solution, while it is not advised to use it in some situations in your case it will work just fine. Just remember one thing always have a **`HEAD`** content, this will prevent reloading problems. But there's one main difference, sides are changed now. At this point **`grap.html`** is fully loaded into the **`DOM`** and when you transit back to **`index.html`** only its **`data-role="page"`** div will be loaded into the **`DOM`**. Basically only downside of your solution is that you can have only one data-role="page" per **`HTML`** file. Where in your first case **`index.html`** could have more then one page inside.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer, just one more thing: Would you know suggest to stay with the second approach or is there a way to stay with the first approach somehow?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't recognize my typo early enough to change it.. I meant "Would you now..."

Comment: You can still use second solution, while it is not advised to use it in some situations in your case it will work just fine. Just remember one thing always have a HEAD content, this will prevent reloading problems. But there's one main difference, sides are changed now. At this point grap.html is fully loaded into the DOM and when you transit back to index.html only its data-role="page" DIV will be loaded into the DOM. Basically only downside of your solution is that you can have only one data-role="page" per HTML file. Where in your first case index.html could have more then one page inside.